# Zend Form Filter and Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, zend-framework2

Havin a Zf2 Registration form and one filter for e-mail is like this:

```
array(
     'name'    => 'Db\NoRecordExists',
     'options' => array(
         'table' => 'user',
         'field' => 'email',
         'adapter' =>  $sm->get ( 'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' ),
         'messages' => array(
              NoRecordExists::ERROR_RECORD_FOUND => 'E-mail address already exists'
         ),
      ),
),
```

This validator check if e-mail address already exists. It works fine but when i try to connect my project with jQuery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#btnRegister").click( function() {

        $("#email").css("border-color", "");
        $("#password").css("border-color", "");
        $("#confirm_password").css("border-color", "");
        $("#emailReg").text("");
        $("#passwordReg").text("");

        var email = $("#email").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();
        var confirm_password = $("#confirm_password").val();
        $("#Register").submit( function() {
           return false;    
        });
        if((/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/.test(email)) != true) {
            $("#email").css("border-color", "red");
            $("#emailReg").text("Invalid email format");
        } else if(password.length < 6) {
            $("#password").css("border-color", "red");
            $("#passwordReg").text("Password must be at least 6 characters long");
        } else if ((password == confirm_password) != true) {
            $("#password").css("border-color", "red");
            $("#confirm_password").css("border-color", "red");
            $("#passwordReg").text("Password doesn't match");
        } else if((/((?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Z]))/gm.test(password)) != true) {
            $("#password").css("border-color", "red");
            $("#passwordReg").text("Password must contian at least one digit and upper case");
        }   else  { 
            $.post( 
            $("#Register").attr("action"),
            $("#Register :input").serializeArray());
            location.href = "auth";
        }   
    });
});
```

This file check for e-mail correct format, also some passwords validators and when all this is correct it redirects to auth page and it should register user into DB. But it doesnt let action from zf module to insert data into db. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Please use `Zend-Framework2` tag for ZF2 related questions

Comment: Check `developer tools-> network`

Comment: It cancels POST form. How can i fix this ?